# How do I loop through Categories to get sub categories and create a nested subcategories array within it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following Categories object array that has the category Id, Category Name and Subcategories

```
{
"categories":[
{
"id_product_cat":1,
"prod_category_name":"food",
"subcategory":"Pizza"
},
{
"id_product_cat":1,
"prod_category_name":"food",
"subcategory":"Burger"
},
{
"id_product_cat":1,
"prod_category_name":"food",
"subcategory":"Chicken"
},
{
"id_product_cat":1,
"prod_category_name":"food",
"subcategory":"Sandwiches"
},
{
"id_product_cat":2,
"prod_category_name":"drinks ",
"subcategory":"Alcoholic Drinks"
},
{
"id_product_cat":2,
"prod_category_name":"drinks ",
"subcategory":"Non-alcoholic Drinks"
},
{
"id_product_cat":2,
"prod_category_name":"drinks ",
"subcategory":"Coffee"
},
{
"id_product_cat":1,
"prod_category_name":"food",
"subcategory":"Test"
}
]
}
```

I want to loop through the Categories array and return a new array with Category Id, Category name a nested subcategories array for each distinct category. My desired out is:

```
{
"categories":[
{
"id_product_cat":1,
"prod_category_name":"food",
"subcategories":["Pizza","Burger","Chicken","Sandwiches"]
},
{
"id_product_cat":2,
"prod_category_name":"drinks ",
"subcategories":["Alcoholic Drinks","Non-alcoholic Drinks","Coffee"]
}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it you need to cut into to 2 parts the problem.

1. First you'll want **to group each categories together**. You can simply do it with a **reduce**. (Why doing it with a reduce? To avoid loop into loop, so complexity).

> ```
> const groupedCategories = obj.categories.reduce((accumulator, element, index) => {
>   const categoryId = element.id_product_cat;
>   const category = element.prod_category_name;
>   const subCategory = element.subcategory;
>
>   if (accumulator[categoryId])
>     return {
>       ...accumulator,
>       [categoryId]: {
>         ...accumulator[categoryId],
>         subCategories: [...accumulator[categoryId].subCategories, subCategory],
>       }
>     };
>   else
>    return {
>     ...accumulator,
>     [categoryId]: {
>       prod_category_name: category,
>       subCategories: [subCategory],
>     }
>   };
> }, {});
> ```

Once you did it, you'll have your categories correctly grouped.

2. Finally, you'll want to **properly format your output**, to do so, you can simply do it with **a loop on your groupedCategories object**, for example just like that:

> ```
> const output = {
>   categories: Object.keys(groupedCategories).map(categoryId => ({
>     id_product_cat: categoryId,
>     prod_category_name: groupedCategories[categoryId].prod_category_name,
>     subcategories: groupedCategories[categoryId].subCategories,
>   }))
> };
> ```

I hope these code samples helped you to find a way to achieve your goal !

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Array.reduce()` to collect all the categories.

```
let data = {
"categories":[
{
"id_product_cat":1,
"prod_category_name":"food",
"subcategory":"Pizza"
},
{
"id_product_cat":1,
"prod_category_name":"food",
"subcategory":"Burger"
},
{
"id_product_cat":1,
"prod_category_name":"food",
"subcategory":"Chicken"
},
{
"id_product_cat":1,
"prod_category_name":"food",
"subcategory":"Sandwiches"
},
{
"id_product_cat":2,
"prod_category_name":"drinks ",
"subcategory":"Alcoholic Drinks"
},
{
"id_product_cat":2,
"prod_category_name":"drinks ",
"subcategory":"Non-alcoholic Drinks"
},
{
"id_product_cat":2,
"prod_category_name":"drinks ",
"subcategory":"Coffee"
},
{
"id_product_cat":1,
"prod_category_name":"food",
"subcategory":"Test"
}
]
}

let existingCategory = acc.find((checkCategory)=>{ return category.id_product_cat === checkCategory.id_product_cat });
if(existingCategory){// checking for existing category
    existingCategory.subcategory.push(category.subcategory);
}else{
    category.subcategory = [category.subcategory];
    acc.push(category);
}
return acc;
},[]);
console.log(categories);
```